# Tabs how can I add next and prev buttons?

Tags: javascript

Tabs how can I add next and prev buttons?

I'm have a tab component that needs the next and prev button as requirements.

I tried to build the component and now the extra bit is needed but I'm a bit stuck.

I'm not sure how to call the function and make it work within the existing one.

How do I add an extra click function for the buttons next and prev?

would be really useful to have it working.  If anyone is able to put me on the right path, perhaps using a click even with some console.log in the right place?

```js
class Tabs {
  constructor() {
    this.tabsBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs-block");
  }

  init() {
    if (this.tabsBlocks.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.tabsBlocks, (tabBlock, index) => {
        const tabContainer = tabBlock.querySelector(".tab-wrapper");
        const tabs = tabBlock.querySelectorAll("button");
        const panels = tabBlock.querySelectorAll(".panel");
        
        const buttonNext = tabBlock.querySelector(".buttonNext");
        const buttonPrev = tabBlock.querySelector(".buttonPrev");

        tabContainer.setAttribute("role", "tablist");

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab) => {
          if (tab.dataset.open === "true") this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);

          tab.setAttribute("role", "tab");
          tab.setAttribute(
            "aria-controls",
            `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`
          );

          const associatedPanel = tabBlock.querySelector(
            `[data-panel="${tab.dataset.target}"]`
          );

          if (associatedPanel !== null) {
            associatedPanel.id = `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${
              index + 1
            }`;
            tab.id = `tab-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`;
          }

          tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);
          });
                   
        });
        
        
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
          const associatedTab = tabBlock.querySelector(
            `[data-target="${panel.dataset.panel}"]`
          );

          panel.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel");
          panel.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", `${associatedTab.id}`);
        });
                
      });
    }
  }

  toggleTabs = (currentTab, panels, buttonNext, buttonPrev) => {
    const tabs = currentTab.closest(".tabs-block").querySelectorAll("button");
    
    const target = currentTab.dataset.target;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab) => {
      if (tab.dataset.target !== target) {
        tab.classList.remove("is-active");
        tab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
      }
    });

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
      if (panel.dataset.panel !== target) {
        panel.classList.remove("is-active");
      } else {
        panel.classList.add("is-active");
        currentTab.classList.add("is-active");
        currentTab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
      }
    });
    
    
       
  };
}

const components = {
  Tabs: new Tabs()
};
components.Tabs.init();
```

```css
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li button {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li button.is-active {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.tabs-block .panel {
  display: none;
}
.tabs-block .panel.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="tabs-block">
  <ul class="tab-wrapper">
    <li><button data-target="1" data-open="true">Tab title 1</button></li>
    <li><button data-target="2">Tab title 2</button></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div data-panel="1" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-panel="2" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 2 content</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<button class="buttonNext"><< Prev</button>
<button class="buttonPrev">Next >></button>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works on codepen but does not in here.. Maybe `babel` preprozessor does something which i do not know...

Copy this to codepen and you will be happy.

```js
class Pagination {

  constructor(tabComponent, prevBtnId, nextBtnId) {
    this.arrayUtils = new ArrayUtils()
    this.tabComponent = tabComponent
    this.prevBtn = document.getElementById(prevBtnId)
    this.nextBtn = document.getElementById(nextBtnId)
    
    // listen to tabComponents newly created Toggle event
    // in which we wanna make sure to disable Btns or something..
    this.tabComponent.onTabsToggle((tabs, tabIndex) => {
        this.applyPaginationRules(tabs, tabIndex)
    })
  }
  
  setDisabled(btn, value) {
    if(value) {
        btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'true')
    } else {
        btn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    }
  }
  
  applyPaginationRules(tabs, newActiveIndex) {
      const nextBtnDisabled = newActiveIndex === (tabs.length -1)
      const prevBtnDisabled = newActiveIndex === 0
  
      this.setDisabled(this.nextBtn, nextBtnDisabled)
      this.setDisabled(this.prevBtn, prevBtnDisabled)
      
  }

  paginate(btn, action) {
   const block = btn.closest('.tabs-block')
   const panels = block.querySelectorAll('.panel')
   const tabs = block.querySelectorAll('.tab-wrapper > li > button')
   const activeIndex = Array.from(tabs)
     .findIndex(t => t.getAttribute('data-open') === 'true')
   
   if (tabs.length < 2) {
     console.log('0 OR 1 tabs to toggle so no action.')
     return
   }
  
   var newActiveIndex 

   if(action === 'next') {
     newActiveIndex = this.arrayUtils.nextIndex(activeIndex, tabs)
   }
  
   else if(action === 'prev') {
     newActiveIndex = this.arrayUtils.previousIndex(activeIndex, tabs)
  }
  
  else {
    throw 'Invalid toggle action ' + action
  }
  
  
  // enable / disable next and previous btns.. 
  this.applyPaginationRules(tabs, newActiveIndex)
  
  this.tabComponent.toggleTabs(tabs[newActiveIndex], panels)
   
}

addPaginationListener(btn, action) {
   btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
       this.paginate(btn, action)
   })
}

init() {
    this.addPaginationListener(this.prevBtn, 'prev')
    this.addPaginationListener(this.nextBtn, 'next')      
    
    // disable prev button on beggining since we start at 0..
    this.setDisabled(this.prevBtn, true)

  }
}


class ArrayUtils {

// getting next index in array
 nextIndex(currentIndex, array) {

 // if 0 OR 1 elements, index stays the same..
   if(array.length < 2) return currentIndex

   // if possible increment.
   if(currentIndex < array.length -1) {
       return currentIndex + 1
   }

   // if index would exceed array size go to start.
   return 0

}

// getting previous INdex in array:
previousIndex(currentIndex, array) {
    // if 0 OR 1 elements, index stays the same..
    if(array.length < 2) return currentIndex

    // if possible decrement!
    if(currentIndex > 0) {
        return currentIndex - 1
    }

    // start at the end of array when end is reached ofc.
    return array.length -1

    }
}


class Tabs {
constructor() {
  this.tabsBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs-block");
  this.onToggleHandlers = []
}

onTabsToggle(fn) {
   this.onToggleHandlers.push(fn)
}

emitTabsToggle(tabs, tabIndex) {
  this.onToggleHandlers.forEach(fn => fn(tabs, tabIndex))
}

init() {
  if (this.tabsBlocks.length > 0) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.tabsBlocks, (tabBlock, index) => {
      const tabContainer = tabBlock.querySelector(".tab-wrapper");
      const tabs = tabBlock.querySelectorAll(".tab-wrapper li button");
      const panels = tabBlock.querySelectorAll(".panel");

      tabContainer.setAttribute("role", "tablist");

      Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab, tabIndex) => {
        if (tab.dataset.open === "true") this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);

        tab.setAttribute("role", "tab");
        tab.setAttribute(
          "aria-controls",
          `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`
        );

        const associatedPanel = tabBlock.querySelector(
          `[data-panel="${tab.dataset.target}"]`
        );

        if (associatedPanel !== null) {
          associatedPanel.id = `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${
            index + 1
          }`;
          tab.id = `tab-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`;
        }

        tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);
          
          this.emitTabsToggle(tabs, tabIndex)
          
        });
      });

      Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
        const associatedTab = tabBlock.querySelector(
          `[data-target="${panel.dataset.panel}"]`
        );

        panel.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel");
        panel.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", `${associatedTab.id}`);
      });
    });
  }
}

toggleTabs = (currentTab, panels) => {
  const tabs = currentTab.closest(".tabs-block").querySelectorAll("button");

  const target = currentTab.dataset.target;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab) => {
    if (tab.dataset.target !== target) {
      tab.classList.remove("is-active");
      tab.setAttribute('data-open', 'false')
      tab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
    }
  });

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
    if (panel.dataset.panel !== target) {
      panel.classList.remove("is-active");
    } else {
      panel.classList.add("is-active");
    }
  });
  
  /// activate tab..
  currentTab.classList.add("is-active");
  currentTab.setAttribute("data-open", 'true');
  currentTab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
};
}

const components = {
Tabs: new Tabs()
};

components.Tabs.init();

// have the pagination more decoupled from tabs!
// it uses tabs component but you can remove it OR apply it to other
// classes like so more easily..
const prevBtnId = 'pagination-prev'
const nextBtnId = 'pagination-next'
const pagination = new Pagination(components.Tabs, prevBtnId, nextBtnId)
pagination.init()
```

```css
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li button {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: rem(20px);
}
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li button.is-active {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.tabs-block .panel {
  display: none;
}
.tabs-block .panel.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="tabs-block">
  <ul class="tab-wrapper">
    <li><button data-target="1" data-open="true">Tab title 1</button></li>
    <li><button data-target="2">Tab title 2</button></li>
    <li><button data-target="3">Tab title 3</button></li>
    <li><button data-target="4">Tab title 4</button></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div data-panel="1" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-panel="2" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-panel="3" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 3 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-panel="4" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 4 content</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="buttonPrev" id="pagination-prev"><< Prev</button>
      <button class="buttonNext" id="pagination-next">Next >></button>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks, great start! I can see only the prev for now, which is fine. But it doesn't change the tabs content.
what happens if I have multiple tabs and not just 2? IS there a way to calculate the last and fist array? so perhaps I can also make them disabled if the are last or first?

Comment: I updated the answer with 2 helper functions for calcualting next/previous index in a given array. Basically the logic of next() / prev()

Comment: This logic goes to the end of array if first is reached, but you can also disable buttons however you want ^^

Comment: thanks this is great.  could you please help me with this code pen? https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/mdqKXLq you can foket it.

Comment: I simply don't know how to programmatically hide one tab and show the other.  If you can give an example on how to do that I can help you.

Comment: simply the click event of the next and prev should bind the buttons tabs I guess?

Comment: Ok I updated the ansewr. The current code works in the provided codepen but i don't have an account and don't want one so check it out yourselve.

Comment: @user173420 Well.. didn't see the sass ... It works fine now ''

Comment: can I be really annoying? is it possible not to have the inline functions 'click event' on the html? 
also, is it possible to to make the buttons loopin? perhaps have the disabled button when is first or last?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242323/discussion-between-silvan-bregy-and-user173420).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add eventListener to your button elements

```
buttonNext.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
buttonPrev.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  console.log("next")
}
```

Comment: would you be a bit more descriptive please? Could you please give me more help?

Comment: what exactly do you want to know? I figured you were looking for the solution I mentioned. Please be more descriptive so I might help

Comment: Well, I have errors when I try to implement the fucntion as the addEventListener: `Cannot read properties of undefined` also I'm not sure  where to place the function. could you please help?

Comment: I have attached another answer please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Here are your Button Elements

```
<button id="nextBtn" class="buttonNext"><< Prev</button>
<button id="prevBtn" class="buttonPrev">Next >></button>
```

You have to get elements directly from DOM. use a unique class name or id for this purpose

```
const buttonNext = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
const buttonPrev = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
```

Now if the buttonNext and buttonPrev variables have the elements you can add eventListener. The event listener is of type click so whenever user clicks on any button the respective function will be called

```
buttonNext && buttonNext.addEventListener("click", handleNext);
buttonPrev && buttonPrev.addEventListener("click", handlePrev);


const handleNext = () => {
  console.log("next")
}

 const handlePrev = () => {
      console.log("next")
    }
```

I hope this will work for you. You can add any logic on next and prev buttons in respective functions

Comment: Thanks, I think we are getting there. https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/RwjyrXg 
but still not sign of the console working. could you please have a look?

Comment: I have made it working. check my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

Working codepen demo

```
class Tabs {
  constructor() {
    this.tabsBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs-block");
  }

  init() {
    if (this.tabsBlocks.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.tabsBlocks, (tabBlock, index) => {
        const tabContainer = tabBlock.querySelector(".tab-wrapper");
        const tabs = tabBlock.querySelectorAll("button");
        const panels = tabBlock.querySelectorAll(".panel");

        const Navigate= () => {
       const buttonNext = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
        const buttonPrev = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
        
        

    const handleNext = () => {
      console.log("next");
    };

    const handlePrev = () => {
      console.log("prev");
    };
          
          buttonNext && buttonNext.addEventListener("click", handleNext);
    buttonPrev && buttonPrev.addEventListener("click", handlePrev);
    }
        
        
       Navigate()

        tabContainer.setAttribute("role", "tablist");

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab) => {
          if (tab.dataset.open === "true") this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);

          tab.setAttribute("role", "tab");
          tab.setAttribute(
            "aria-controls",
            `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`
          );

          const associatedPanel = tabBlock.querySelector(
            `[data-panel="${tab.dataset.target}"]`
          );

          if (associatedPanel !== null) {
            associatedPanel.id = `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${
              index + 1
            }`;
            tab.id = `tab-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`;
          }

          tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);
          });
        });

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
          const associatedTab = tabBlock.querySelector(
            `[data-target="${panel.dataset.panel}"]`
          );

          panel.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel");
          panel.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", `${associatedTab.id}`);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  toggleTabs = (currentTab, panels, buttonNext, buttonPrev) => {
    const tabs = currentTab.closest(".tabs-block").querySelectorAll("button");

    const target = currentTab.dataset.target;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab) => {
      if (tab.dataset.target !== target) {
        tab.classList.remove("is-active");
        tab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
      }
    });

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
      if (panel.dataset.panel !== target) {
        panel.classList.remove("is-active");
      } else {
        panel.classList.add("is-active");
        currentTab.classList.add("is-active");
        currentTab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
      }
    });
    
    

    
  };
}

const components = {
  Tabs: new Tabs()
};
components.Tabs.init();
```

Comment: thanks, https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/mdqKXLq I made the pen, is there a way to trigget the tabs on those 2 functions?